# Tensorflow gradient tape calculation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent, gradienttape

I am trying to understand the purpose of `TF GRADIENT TAPE`, in the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
var = tf.Variable(5.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    op = (2*var)+(var*var)
    diff = tape.gradient(op,var)
print (diff)
```

Op:

`diff = tf.Tensor(12.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)`

I am confused because since `var=5`, the `op=(2*5)+(5*5)=>35`, and if I am `calculating the derivative of a constant` then `diff should be 0`

I understand the reason its `12`, because its not taking the `var` as `5` instead `(2*var)+(var*var)=> 2var+var**2` so calculating the derivative of this function becomes `2+2*var=>12`.

But what I dont understand is, why the value given for `var` is not considered?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean the value given for `var` is not considered? The gradient `2+2*var` is clearly a function of `var`.

Comment: @rchome if the given value of ```var``` is considered in the ```tape``` then the derivative should be ```0``` right?

Comment: `var` is a variable, not a constant. The derivative of `op` with respect to `var` is 12 in this case. If you instead used `var = tf.constant(5.0)`, you would get `None` for the gradient since the `GradientTape` is not "watching" `var`. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#controlling_what_the_tape_watches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is producing the right result.
`tf.GradientTape` context that will automatically record every operation
that involves a variable.
If you consider the partial derivative for the below function with regard to `var`

```
def v(var):
  return 2 * var + var * var
```

It will be `2 + 2*var`, when the value of `var=5` it will be `2 + 2*5` which is 12 returned by the gradient below.

```
var = tf.Variable(5.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  z = v(var)
diff = tape.gradient(z,var)
print (diff)
tf.Tensor(12.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Try changing the variable to different values, for the function `v`, the equation `2 + 2*var` holds good.